# How can i get the link of submisson in subbredit

Tags: python-3.x, api, url, reddit, praw

when im calling `submisson.url` i get something like i.redd.it/... . But when I open a post in the subreddit I get the fowling url https://www.reddit.com/r/PrequelMemes/comments/ is there a method which returns https://www.reddit.com/r/PrequelMemes/comments/? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `submission.permalink`. There's a really helpful list of a bunch of these somewhat hard-to-discover attributes in [the documentation of `Subreddit`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html).

Answer (score 0):

PRAW submission object has two attributes `url` and `permalink` for getting the url of a submission.

`submission.url` will return the URL of the image that is inside the post and `submission.permalink` will return the main URL of the submission.

So, in other words, `submission.url` will give you a URL that starts with `https://i.redd.it` and `submission.permalink` will give you the URL that starts with `https://reddit.com/r/PrequelMemes/comments/?...`

I hope you get it. :)